# Como agregar boton editar y eliminar en app en Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, mysql, android, app, apk

Tengo esta vista en la que se llenaran los datos del pedido.

**Quiero saber como agregar un botón que edite las ordenes y otro de eliminar **
Quiero saber esos detalles adjunto todo el código y las vistas necesarias para la realizacion de esos cambios, la aplicación se corre en android studio en JAVA

[image: Formulario]

el código de esa vista es la siguiente

```
 public static void enviarOrden(Context context, String IDEmpresa, String fechadeseada, String horario,
                                   String flete, String extras, ArrayList<ListModel> Items,
                                   Map<String, String[]> mapeoResiduos, String especificacionr){
        String url = "https://netnegocios.mx/ws_sitrasa_pruebas/si/agregar_orden.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Si la transacción es exitosa
                if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    for(ListModel item:Items){

                       String idResiduo = mapeoResiduos.get(item.getNombreResiduo())[0].split(",")[0]; //AQUI ESTA EL ERRROR DEL ID RESIDUO

                        String Residuo = item.getNombreResiduo();

                        setResiduos(context,
                                response,
                                idResiduo,
                                Residuo,
                                item.getUnidadResiduo(),
                                item.getCantidadResiduo()
                        );
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Orden enviada. Por favor, espere confirmación en la pantalla de 'Confirmación de Servicios'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
  //                  private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No enviado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("idempresa", IDEmpresa);
                params.put("fechadeseada", fechadeseada);
                params.put("horario", horario);
                params.put("flete", flete);
                params.put("extras", extras);
                params.put("especificacionr", especificacionr);
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Ejecución del request
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

mientras que la vista de la orden de recolección es la siguiente

[image: ordenes]

y la consulta de la vista es la siguiente.

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("conexion.php");


//VERIFICACION DE ESCRITURA DE DATOS EN EL FORM
if (!isset($_POST['idempresa'])){
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('agregar orden: No ID!');
}

try{

$sqlQuery = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO 137_dc_ordenrecoleccion (idempresa, fechadeseada, horario, flete, extras, metodorecoleccion, especificacionr) VALUES(". $_POST['idempresa'] . ", STR_TO_DATE('" . $_POST['fechadeseada'] . "', '%Y,%c,%e'), '" . $_POST['horario'] . "', " .  $_POST['flete'] . ", " .  $_POST['extras'] . ", '" .  $_POST['metodo'] . "' ,'" .  $_POST['especificacionr'] ."')");
$sqlQuery->execute();
$sqlQuery->store_result();
$sqlQuery->fetch();

$sqlQuery = $conexion->prepare('SELECT id FROM 137_dc_ordenrecoleccion WHERE idempresa = ' . $_POST['idempresa'] . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ' );
$sqlQuery->execute();
$sqlQuery->store_result();
$sqlQuery->bind_result($idorden);
$sqlQuery->fetch();

if($sqlQuery->num_rows > 0){
    echo $idorden;  
}
else{
    echo 'null';
}
    
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$conexion->close();

?>
```

**Quiero saber como agregar un botón que edite las ordenes y otro de eliminar **
Quiero saber esos detalles adjunto todo el código y las vistas necesarias para la realizacion de esos cambios, la aplicación se corre en android studio en JAVA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar la propiedad OnClickListener de tu ListView/RecyclerView y desde ahí desplegar un AlertDialog donde preguntes si desea modificar o eliminar la orden, otra opción es añadir dos botones a tu diseño dentro de cada fila.

Comment: Pero como hago eso jeje es mi duda!! :(